# Akka class variable scope issues

Tags: scala, scope, mapreduce, akka

How to set mapActors variable to be global outside of the receive function within the MasterActor class?

The `f1` and `f2` functions are sent to the MastorActor from the MapReduceApp.

Another approach is to create the mapActors before the receive function in MastorActor. And then later when receiving the `f1`/`f2` functions from MapReduceApp, `f1` and `f2` could be sent to the mapActors and reduceActors, respectively. But how to achieve this? Passing `f1` and `f2` functions into mapActor and reduceActor seems to be a headache.

```scala
class MasterActor extends Actor {
  var reduceActors = List[ActorRef]()
  var mapActors: ActorRef = ???
  def receive = {
    case SetMapperReducer(f1, f2, data) =>
      for (i <- 0 until 4) {
        reduceActors = context.actorOf(
          Props(classOf[ReduceActor], f2), name = "reduce" + i
        ) :: reduceActors
      }
      mapActors = context.actorOf(
        RoundRobinPool(4).props(
          Props(classOf[MapActor], reduceActors, f1)
        )
      )
    case Flush =>
      mapActors ! Broadcast(Flush)
}
```

Two classes for map and reduce.

Map actor:

```scala
class MapActor(
  reduceActors: List[ActorRef],
  mf: Any => List[Tuple2[Any,Any]]
) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case MapData(data: Any) =>
      println(data)
    case Flush =>
      println("Got flush")
  }
}

class ReduceActor(rf: Any => List[Tuple2[Any,Any]]) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Data(data: Any) =>
      println(data)
    case Flush =>
      println("Got flush")
}
```

And a main program:

```scala
object MapReduceApp extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("TestApp")
  val master = system.actorOf(Props[MasterActor](), name = "master")
  val data = List(
    ("Episode 1", "Once upon a time, in a land far, far away...")
  )
  master ! SetMapperReducer(mapProcess1 _, reduceProcess1 _, data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `var` in Actors, use `context.become` to handle state. Something like this:

```
class MasterActor extends Actor {
  def receive = receiveMain(Nil, None)

  def receiveMain(
      reduceActors: List[ActorRef],
      mapActor: Option[ActorRef],
  ): Receive = {
    case SetMapperReducer(f1, f2, data) =>
      val reduceActors =
        (0 until 4).map { i =>
          context.actorOf(
            Props(classOf[ReduceActor], f2),
            name = "reduce" + i
          )
        }.toList
      val mapActors = context.actorOf(
        RoundRobinPool(4).props(
          Props(classOf[MapActor], reduceActors, f1)
        )
      )

      context.become(reduceActors, Option(mapActors))

    case Flush =>
      mapActors.foreach(_ ! Broadcast(Flush))
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears creating a TestActor class initially for the mapActors variable seems to do the trick. Then later it can be changed within the case.

Master actor:

```scala
  ...
  var mapActors = context.actorOf(
      RoundRobinPool(numberMappers).props(
        Props(classOf[TestActor])
      )
    )
  def receive = {
    case SetMapperReducer(f1, f2, data) =>
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Then just create temp TestActor class:

```scala
class TestActor() extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Flush =>
      println("hi")
  }
}
```